# webview shouldOverrideUrlLoading multiple url

Tags: android, url, webview, overriding

i'm trying to load two different url in a webview, but it seems something went wrong or maybe webview does not allow override multiple url in single webview?. first url is my site url, the second one is my community facebook page, the first one is opened in a webview but not the other one. 
this is my codes:

```
@Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("mysite.com")){
            return false;
        } else if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("facebook.com")){
        return false;
        }
        else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

And that was my first attempt, the second is:

```
@Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if ((Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("mysite.com"))|| (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("facebook.com"))){
            return false;
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I tried to replace facebook url with another site url but still no luck.
I am new to android so any explanations would be appreciated, thank you in advance..

err, maybe the problem is inside here? since loadUrl only load mysite url and not the other url?:

```
  mwebView.loadUrl("mysite full url");

    //handle link inside app
    mwebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebviewClient());
```